# mysql date_add 2 times in procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dateadd

i want to use Date_add 2 times in a procedure, but it returns 0 rows (while it should return rows)

Here is the procedure

```
 select av.*, ap.*,c.* from tbl_available av 
 left join tbl_appointment ap on av.avHours = ap.appointmenttime 
 and ap.calendarid = kalenderId 
 and ap.appointmentdate = DATE_ADD(dag, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
 left join tbl_client c on ap.clientid = c.clientid
 where av.avCalendarId = KalenderId 
 and av.avDays = DayOfweek(DATE_ADD(dag, INTERVAL 6 DAY)) 
 order by avHours;
```

it works without the date_add

thanks in advance!

//edit

What i have now:

```
select av.*, ap.*,c.*, ab.absentid from tbl_available av 
left join tbl_appointment ap on av.avHours = ap.appointmenttime 
and ap.calendarid = kalenderId 
and ap.appointmentdate BETWEEN dag AND DATE_ADD(dag, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
and (av.avDays = DayOfweek(ap.appointmentdate) OR ap.appointmentdate IS NULL)
left join tbl_client c on ap.clientid = c.clientid
left join tbl_absent ab on av.avHours = ab.ababsent
and ab.abHoliday = dag
and ab.abCalendarID = kalenderId
where av.avCalendarId = kalenderId 
order by avDays,avHours;
```

But the ab.absentid is not fetched, why is that? :(

Comment: What's your sample data and expected output? This looks ok on first glance.

Comment: Agree with lc, syntactically it seems fine.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: hi, it's a bit to big to post here, but i want all the tbl_available data with (if there are) corresponding tbl_appointment data and the corresponding tbl_client data from 1 day. This works, but now i want it from 1 week, and that results in 0 rows. but if i use the same date for 1 day it gives rows, so i'm sure this procedure must return   rows

Comment: You're only looking at the one day 6 days after `dag`. Is this what you intend, or do you mean to be looking at a range of dates (= one week)?

Comment: OW yes, i want the whole week, can i do that without a loop? ( i thought this was the code for the whole week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you want, but for the whole week, try something like:

```
select av.*, ap.*,c.* from tbl_available av 
left join tbl_appointment ap on av.avHours = ap.appointmenttime 
and ap.calendarid = kalenderId 
and ap.appointmentdate BETWEEN dag AND DATE_ADD(dag, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
and (av.avDays = DayOfweek(ap.appointmentdate) OR ap.appointmentdate IS NULL)
left join tbl_client c on ap.clientid = c.clientid
where av.avCalendarId = KalenderId 
order by avHours;
```

I'm using `BETWEEN` to specify the date range for `ap.appointmentdate`. The `av.avDays` is changed to either correlate to `ap.appointmentdate` or also show rows with no appointment (assumed this behavior because you have a `LEFT JOIN` on `tbl_appointment`). I have left off `DayOfweek(dag) ...` because you are looking at a whole week so this is redundant.

Comment: This is exactly what i want! thanks, i forgot the between! :) good idea to leave out the Daysofweek, i didn't thought about that :)

Comment: there's an error in this query, it only shows the records with matching clients, but i also want all the avDays, where there are no appointments and thus no clients. and i don't have a clue how to make an outer join from this query

Comment: @schoen I'm not sure what to say though unless KalendarId is coming from one of the joined tables and that condition needs to be in the ON clause, not the main WHERE clause?

Comment: no KalenderId & dag are the 2 input parameters, i'm rewriting this now   with a loop, i hope this works.

Comment: @schoen Ok, I have edited the query, you should get all `tbl_available` rows this way.

Comment: hey, i got one more question. i edited the first post. Maybe you could take a look at it for me? i promise it's the last question i ask about this $**% procedure:D

Comment: @schoen The query looks ok to me on first glance. I wonder if there's just no corresponding row? Maybe you didn't mean `ab.abHoliday = dag` but instead wanted to show for the whole week (like `ab.abHoliday BETWEEN dag AND DATE_ADD(dag INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND DayOfweek(ab.abHoliday) = av.avDays)`? But then if there are multiple rows for `ab` and `ap`, you're going to get the product of these rows. I don't know your structure though.

Comment: Cheers mate, this one did the trick, i forget the between again *shame*. it's impossible to get multiple rows in ab or ap, so that's not an issue :) thanks for helping me out